# Modify default constructor in CodeTypeDeclaration

Tags: c#, code-generation

I've written some code to generate .NET types from XML schemas coming out of our CMS. This is going smoothly and producing the results I am expecting.

Now I want to customize the default (parameterless) constructor of a generated type. I have some code that looks like:

```
CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace("MyNamespace");

// import type mappings from schema
// export type mappings into codeNamespace

CodeTypeDeclaration codeType = codeNamespace.Types.First();
```

At this point, I can successfully modify `codeType`; adding/removing attributes, properties, etc.

However, inspecting the `Members` property of the `codeType` indicates that there is not yet a default constructor defined. Sure I could add one; but when I go to write out the code string (using `CSharpCodeProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace`), *another* default constructor is added to the output (in this case, for setting some default values on fields derived from the schema).

What I'm trying to do is basically insert a call to a method inside the default constructor (a method that I can successfully add to `codeType` as per above).

**(How) can I deal with the fact that when I write out the code string, a default constructor** (that wasn't present in the `Members` collection before) **is inserted?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel a bit silly...

I confused myself during debugging - was looking at a `codeType` that **did not** define a default constructor and comparing to generated source with a type that **did** contain a default constructor.

I was able to use code similar to the following to handle both cases:

```
var ctor = codeType.Members
                   .Cast<CodeTypeMember>()
                   .SingleOrDefault(m => m.GetType() == typeof(CodeConstructor));
if (ctor == null)
{
    //codeType didn't define a default constructor, so create one
    ctor = new CodeConstructor() { Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public };
}
else
{
    //codeType did define a default constructor, remove it before modifying
    codeType.Members.Remove(ctor);
}

//make some modifications to ctor

//add ctor to the codeType
codeType.Members.Add(ctor);
```